# Форматирование вывода времени

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая из секунд конвертит в часы, минуты, секунды.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    // cor do cmd (verde)
    system("color 2");
    // variaveis decimais
    int vremya, chasi, minuti, secundi;

    printf("Vvedite vremya v secundah: ");
    scanf("%i", &vremya);

    // calculos
    chasi = vremya / 3600;
    minuti = vremya * 60;
    secundi = vremya;

    // apresenta os resultados
    printf("\nVremya: %i:%i.%i\t ", chasi, minuti, secundi);

    // pause
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Но программа пишет неправильные цифры, помогите решить. Не знаю, к чему склониться.

Comment: @extazys, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
hr = s/60/60; //пересчитываем секунды в часы
mn = s/60; //пересчитываем секунды в минуты 
sc = s%60; //остаток от деления в секундах 
printf("\nTime: %i:%i.%i\t ", hr , mn , sc);
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что для величины 7270 автор хочет увидеть 2 часа, 1 минута и 10 сек, а не 2 часа, 121 минута и 10 сек.

    mn = (s - hr*3600)/60; 

Хотя, вопрос сформулирован так, что понять можно по разному.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Думаю не мне одному полезно будет